# No wireless network on list

Tags: wireless, virtualbox

I'm using VMBOX for linux with ALFA-AWUS036NH. My wlan0 is done,every update is ok but i can't see wireless routers. Empty. Why that can be happen ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other versions, but 16.04 works with WiFi if you don't update it.

What I did was reinstall Lubuntu 16.04 and not do updates as I installed it.  Then, I did updates, but unchecked updating security updates for networking. After the updates and only networking was left, I opened the list of updates for networking. The top two were for wireless and the bottom was generic or something.  I unchecked the bottom one and left the last one unchecked to do the final update.

When the update finished, I checked for updates and it said there were no more updates to do.  Whatever that bottom box was, it went away and I have had no more problems doing WiFi with my Lubuntu installation.

This is more of a prevention than a repair, but it's how I got it to work after fighting with it for two days.